# SQLServerException; The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed

Tags: sql-server

Using this connection string

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=mydb;user=username;password=psw
```

I am getting the following error that  I cannot figure out how to solve it:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.

I looked at the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<Instance Name>\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp`, the port is set, and the firewall is disabled, the instance is running and the user does have master default access privilege!, So what was wrong?

Comment: your conncetion string look ok.. but jus try it this way and see `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;user=username;password=psw'`

Comment: Just tried that, getting: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "mydb" requested by the login. The login failed`.

Comment: is database `mydb` exists? with given username and password permissions?

Comment: @JAG thank you for letting me thinking about it, I didn't change the db but the user, using `sa` with its password it works, I don't know what was wrong then?!

Comment: So how can I give the permission to another login besides `sa` on this db?, please put an answer for this whole problem now, @JAG, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this connection string

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;user=username;‌​password=psw'
```

and make sure you have this

```
instanceName = SQLEXPRESS;
database = mydb;  -- database mydb should exists
user = userName;‌ -- user should exits and have permission to mydb
​password = userPassword
```

to create new user

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [userName] WITH PASSWORD=N'userPassword', 
             DEFAULT_DATABASE=[YourDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

to give access to `YourDB`

```
GO
USE [YourDB] -- in your case its mydb
GO
CREATE USER [userName] FOR LOGIN [userName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, I created a new user with the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to SQL Server Configuration Manager -->> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
in the right tab  change the properties of  TCP/IP
1- Enable the protocol
2- At IP Addresses : make sure that all TCP Port are 1433
3- Apply -->> Ok
4- Restart SQL Server

I hope it worked well

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the port number, or use a comma in place of the colon.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;user=username;password=psw

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;database=mydb;user=username;password=psw
```